# How to specify dependncies for Slurm jobs?

Tags: queue, cluster-computing, slurm

I would like to submit 4 jobs to the Slurm queue with the following dependencies:

- Job1: `-`, no dependencies
- Job2: `afterok : 1`, only starts if Job1 finishes successfully
- Job3: `afterok : 2`, only starts if Job2 finishes successfully
- Job4: `afternotok:1 OR afternotok:2 OR afterany:3`, only starts if Job1 or Job2 didn't finish successfully or Job3 finishes (`--dependency=afterok:1?afterok:2?afterany:3`).

The issue I am experiencing is that Job4 never starts if Job3 finishes successfully. How do I need to specify the dependencies of Job4 to start even though Job3 finishes successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The text and the command are contradictory? You say after**not**okay in the text, but in the example you use afterok. This should work:

```
--dependency=afternotok:1?afternotokay:2?afterany:3
```